# Fill a zend::form select from db

Tags: zend-framework

I have a result array fetched form database. It's structure in print_r is like this :

Array ( [id] => 1 [code] => MSjoo7 [description] => Hello World [Organization_id] => 1 )

Now I want to set these fetched values in my Zend Form's elements some think like this:

```
Code: MSj007
Description : Hello World
```

https://imageshack.com/lost/0jscreenshotxlsp

For getting above output I also used :

```
$Form->populate( $result_array);
```

but the browser does not show anything.

Answer (score 1):

We only need to add

```
$grades = new Default_Model_Grade( );//create object of grade table in my db
$code = $grades->getGradesByOrganizaton( 1 );//call method of grade class
$form->populate($result[0]->toArray());//fetch all rows from db and then populate
```

in the controller file. But the form fields id must be same as defined in database.